# Call a method from another class

Tags: c#

I'm wanting to know how I can call a method from another class without having to make a new instance of that class. I've looked up this and 90% of the examples I see require me to make a new copy of my referenced class.

Something like this:

```
Fooclass test = new Fooclass();
test.CallMethod();
```

However, I'm wondering if there is a way I can call the method without making a new class instance. Right now I've tried the following in unity.

```
public ImageLoader image; 
void Start () 
{
    image = gameObject.GetComponent<ImageLoader>() as ImageLoader;
}

void OnClick()
{
    image.MoveForward();
}
```

however, when I run this I get the following error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

i know this would be settled with making a new instance of my image loader class but I can't do that as it is holding a lot of data I don't want duplicated multiple times.

Comment: you could make the method static and call it using `ClassName.Method()`.

Comment: Regarding your code, you do not need `as ImageLoader` as `GetComponent<ImageLoader>` already has casted it for you. Regarding your error, the `gameObject` you're referring to likely does not have an `ImageLoader` component assigned to it; double-check that it's there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can. The first way is to make your class to be static.

```
public static class Fooclass
{
    // I don't know the return type of your CallMethod, so I used the void one.
    public static void CallMethod()
    {

    }
}
```

This way, whenever to your code you can call the `CallMethod()` like the following:

```
Fooclass.CallMethod()
```

Another apporach it would be to define a static method in your current class, without the class needed to be static, like the following:

```
public class Fooclass
{
    // I don't know the return type of your CallMethod, so I used the void one.
    public static void CallMethod()
    {

    }
}
```

Now since all the instances of the `Fooclass` would share the same method called `CallMethod`, you can call it like below:

```
Fooclass.CallMethod()
```

without again needed to instantiate an object of type Fooclass, despite the fact that now Fooclass isn't a static class now !

For further documentation please take a look to the link [Static classes and Static Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx).

Comment: The class doesn't need to be static, no matter the place of usage. It's just, __if__ the class contains __only__ static members, making the class static prevents people from creating a class instance that is not intended to provide any instance specific functionality.

Comment: @grek40 This is why I have mentiond the second approach, where you can define a static method in a non static class. Of course you don't have to mark a class as static if your only intention is one of the class methods to be called without creating an object.

Comment: It might be a wording issue but to me it reads as if it would be important to have the static method in the current class in order to make it work with a static method in a non-static class.

Answer (score 2):

Make a static class / static method. Making the method static is good enough if you do not want your class to be static.

```
class my_Class
{
    public static void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}

my_Class.Print();
```

Answer (score 1):

If the method of your other class is not using any instance level variables then you can make it static and use it like

```
Fooclass.CallMethod();
```

Comment: Another workaround would be to make the data static. He has problems with ImageLoader being too big, why not just make THAT static?

Answer (score 1):

The marked answers fit to your question, however please also note that your original Problem seems to be different.

I wonder if the original Problem that results in your `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error is that your method named `OnClick()` is either called before your `Start()` method or that the call `image = gameObject.GetComponent<ImageLoader>() as ImageLoader;` never returns a valid instance of your desired class, therefore `image`  is always null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a `static` member in your static/non-static `class`. The `static` member is callable on a `class` even when no instance of the class has been created.

For eg:

```
public class Automobile
{
    public static int NumberOfWheels = 4;
    public static int SizeOfGasTank
    {
        get
        {
            return 15;
        }
    }
    public static void Drive() { }
    public static event EventType RunOutOfGas;

    // Other non-static fields and properties...
}
```

`Static` members are initialized before the `static` member is accessed for the first time and before the `static` constructor, if there is one, is called. To access a static class member, use the name of the class instead of a variable name to specify the location of the member, as shown in the following example:

```
Automobile.Drive();
int i = Automobile.NumberOfWheels;
```

The `static` member is always accessed by the `class` name, not the instance name. Only one copy of a `static` member exists, regardless of how many instances of the class are created. `Static` methods and properties cannot access non-static fields and events in their containing type, and they cannot access an instance variable of any object unless it is explicitly passed in a method parameter.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx

Hope this helps you.

Shishir